# Danfo.js in Node.js AWS Lambda function

Tags: node.js, aws-lambda, danfojs

Is there a way to use danfo.js with AWS lambda? When I zip the node_modules with the node.js code, it's over the 50MB limit.

Comment: I was able to get around this limit be using **es-build**.